# how to change button name for form Control in react js with bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

iam using react JS with bootstrap and i add form group to upload my images and videos
i want to change the "Choose Files" to some thing else how can i do that there is no docs in bootstrap for change the name of the button

[image]

```
<Form.Group  controlId="formFileMultiple" className="mb-3">
         <Form.Label>add photos and videos</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control  onChange={(e) => {
          console.log(e.target.files);
          setmedia(e.target.files);
        }} type="file" multiple />
        </Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the text by hiding the user agent button and replacing it with your own pseudo element in CSS:

```css
input[type="file"].form-control::file-selector-button {
  display: none;
}

input[type="file"].form-control::before {
  content: attr(value) "Different text"; /*<-- any text you want */
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  border: 0 solid;
  border-color: inherit;
  border-inline-end-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #212529;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: -0.5rem -1rem;
  margin-inline-end: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out,
    border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="file"].form-control.form-control-lg::before {
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  margin: -0.75rem -1rem;
  margin-inline-end: 1rem;
}
```

#### [Demo on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-file-input-component-demo-xlb79g)

Comment: thank you bro great answer can i change also the "No file chosen" ?